# Pattern - Communication that is always initiated by the same party

Tags: design-patterns

I need help finding an efficient pattern for a part of the application I'm developing.

Every user has a device called a *Gateway*. These gateways are communicating with the online system of the application via the *GatewayLogic*. So the *GatewayLogic* is the entry-point to the online system and all user's gateways are connected to it. This communication is done via the 3G-network.

There is one constraint. Since IP-addresses on the 3G-network change frequently, communication between a *Gateway* and the *GatewayLogic* always has to be initiated by the *Gateway*. The problem is that data has to travel both ways. Data has to reach the gateways from the online system and data has to reach the online system from the gateways. So this is essentially two way communication that is always initiated by one component, the *Gateway*.

I'm thinking about tackling this by having the *GatewayLogic* maintain a queue for every *gateway*. Each *Gateway* periodically polls his queue on the *GatewayLogic* for new data. But I'm not sure if this solution is scalable enough.

My question is: Is there a design pattern to solve this problem in a more efficient manner?

Comment: No it's not a web application. The use of 3G is purely so that the application is PnP and setup by the user only requires plugging the gateway into a power socket. It is not standard request-response communication. The Gateways send data to the GatewayLogic without any response required. The GatewayLogic can request specific data or issue commands on the Gateways but the problem is that only the gateways can initiate the communication. That's why I introduced polling queues in my proposed solution.

Comment: I don't think that your assumption, of the GatewayLogic being the server and the Gateways being the clients, is correct. The Gateway does not issue a request to the GatewayLogic, it only passes data. The GatewayLogic however, does issue requests to the Gateways. It can request data and request the Gateway to perform a certain action. So in this case, the Gateway is the server and the GatewayLogic is the client. But there are many servers and only the servers can initiate the communication.

Comment: Yes, I did. Why? The GatewayLogic needs to do the requests to the Gateways but only the Gateways can initiate the communication. That's the problem. That's not a standard web application and it's certainly not standard client-server architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you do not want to use something like a socket (websocket if it is web app) or any other push technology, as you always want communication to be initiated by Gateway, having a queue for each gateway could be a good solution, but can have major issues if you don't limit the queue size, specially if there are too many gateways and connection drop may happen.

Are you sure you cannot use anything like a long polling or sockets? You can easily handle change in IP by handling network change status and doing socket migration in case of IP change.

Maybe you can try to do a modification of comet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) protocol to find a way out

Comment: I'm sure that I can't use any other solution. I guess I'll stick to my current polling queue